# EF unable to find composite key of type GUID and string

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

In my EF application the model (generated from existing DB) has a composite key of ID, and Group_ID, where ID = GUID, and Group_ID is a 4 digit string.

Im attempting to do something like this:

```
Dim foo = db.users.find(user.ID, user.Group_ID)
```

I get the error that a value of string cannot be converted to guid. I believe this is because it is combining the values into a string and attempting to use that then fails. Is there a different way .Find() should be called for composite key of GUID + String?

Comment: the order that you pass the keys into the `Find` method is specific, specified in the ColumnAttribute for each key.  You are probably passing these values in the wrong order.

Comment: I tried both orders to no avail.

Comment: do you have an order defined on your model?